# Gradle with Kotlin DSL expecting Property<String> error

Tags: kotlin, gradle, avro

I need to set this

```
avro {
    templateDirectory = "/path/to/velocity/templates"
}
```

But getting error stating that's it's expecting `Property<String>` not a `String`.

Not clear on how to set this value as `Property<String>`?

Comment: Can you try `templateDirectory.set("/path/to/velocity/templates" as String?)` within the `avro` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [gradle-avro-plugin](https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin), do note that the configuration should be set as below for Kotlin DSL

```
avro {
    templateDirectory.set("/path/to/velocity/templates" as String?)
}
```

The syntax for all the configurations are as below:

```
avro {
    isCreateSetters.set(true)
    isCreateOptionalGetters.set(false)
    isGettersReturnOptional.set(false)
    fieldVisibility.set("PUBLIC_DEPRECATED")
    outputCharacterEncoding.set("UTF-8")
    stringType.set("String")
    templateDirectory.set(null as String?)
    isEnableDecimalLogicalType.set(true)
    dateTimeLogicalType.set("JSR310")
}
```

The reference is [here](https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin#kotlin-dsl-support).